# Writing to the text of a new console window

Tags: c#, process, cmd, stdin

I am trying to write to the standard input of a new console process whenever a new `char` is received by a server. Here is my code:

```
var process = Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
{
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
});

Server.CharReceived += (sender, e) => { process.StandardInput.Write(e.Char); }
```

I expected it to write to the inner text of the console window, but instead it writes to the title:

[image: console window]

How can I make it write to the window's inner text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a process in your code you could just run your project as a console app and then call Console.Write or Console.Writeline whenever a new character is received.  I'm not sure if that will work for your situation but given the information you provided that seems to be the easiest approach.

Comment: I can't do this since I want to create a new console window for every client that connects to the server.